# rkafka.read() doesn't return a message (Returns double quotes only)

Tags: r, apache-kafka, rkafka

Trying to return a message through rkafka library in R.

Followed the same rkafka documentation @ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rkafka/vignettes/rkafka.pdf

Output returns `""` without the actual message in it. Kafka tool confirms that the message is sent by the producer.

CODE:

```
prod1=rkafka.createProducer("127.0.0.1:9092")
rkafka.send(prod1,"test","127.0.0.1:9092","Testing once")
rkafka.closeProducer(prod1)
consumer1=rkafka.createConsumer("127.0.0.1:2181","test")
print(rkafka.read(consumer1))
```

Output:

```
[1] ""
```

Desired Output would return `"Testing once"`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the messages of a topic that have already been written to the topic (before the consumer has been started) you need to set offset value to the smallest possible (equivalent to `--from-beginning`). According to [rkafka docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rkafka/rkafka.pdf) `autoOffseetReset` argument defaults to `largest`

> **autoOffsetReset** 
>   
> smallest : automatically reset the offset to the
>   smallest offset 
> largest : automatically reset the offset to the
>   largest offset 
> anything else: throw exception to the consumer
>   
> Required:Optional 
> Type:String 
> default:largest

In order to be able to consume messages you need to set `autoOffsetReset` to `"smallest"`.

```
consumer1=rkafka.createConsumer("127.0.0.1:2181","test", autoOffsetReset="smallest")
```

Comment: Still doesn't return the message. Says "" again.

Comment: @DawoodAbbas Try to pass a `groupId` as well. `consumer1=rkafka.createConsumer("127.0.0.1:2181","test", autoOffsetReset="smallest", groupId="test-group-v2")`

Comment: Replicated the same createConsumer like that in the documentation, no luck.

Comment: What if you run `kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic test --from-beginning`? Is the message printed out?

Comment: I see the message using Kafka tool which means the producer is doing its job, the issue is probably with the consumer which cannot get the receive the message and then print it into the console. @Giorgos Myrianthous

Comment: Can you try to consume messages using a `SimpleConsumer` and see what happens?

Comment: Also, did you try to include the group id?

Comment: Yes I did, No luck. @Giorgos Myrianthous.

Comment: Docs are quite confusing and they mention that consumerTimeOut, groupId etc are mandatory parameters but the function won't complain if you don't pass them. So my last gues would be to pass all the parameters and see if this is working: `consumer2=rkafka.createConsumer("127.0.0.1:2181","test","test-consumer-group","50000","1000", "true", "60000", "smallest")`

Answer (score 0):

Update: This Code Works:

```
library(rkafka)

prod1=rkafka.createProducer("127.0.0.1:9092")
rkafka.send(prod1,"test","127.0.0.1:9092","Testing once")
rkafka.send(prod1,"test","127.0.0.1:9092","Testing twice")

rkafka.closeProducer(prod1)
consumer1=rkafka.createConsumer("127.0.0.1:2181","test",groupId = "test-consumer- 
group",zookeeperConnectionTimeoutMs = "100000",autoCommitEnable = "NULL", 
autoCommitInterval = "NULL",autoOffsetReset = "NULL")


print(rkafka.read(consumer1))
print(rkafka.readPoll(consumer1))
rkafka.closeConsumer(consumer1)
```

The key is to restart Kafka after deleting the logs it generates.

Comment: Wouldn't call this as a "key". This means that you have lost everything and you have started consumption again.